# Display minutes as H:MM

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with integers that represent a minute count (not an actual time of day, since it can store values larger than 24 hours and negative ones) and I want to add a second column to display them as hours and minutes, e.g.:

```
   A     B
---- -----
   5  0:05
  30  0:30
  60  1:00
  90  1:30
1440 24:00
1800 30:00
 -45 -0:45
```

I've got quite close:

1. Set column B to `=A1/(24*60)`.
2. Apply `[h]:mm;@` custom format.

But negative values display as `#########`.

What's the bit I'm missing?

Comment: Negative time is always shown as "########". Display the data you need as a string, not as a time.

Comment: You could also change a date system option in Excel https://cdn.extendoffice.com/images/stories/doc-excel/show-negative-time/doc-show-negative-time3.png

Comment: @Akina How do I cast to string? Or perhaps you mean that I meed to use an entirely different approach and build everything with string functions like concatenation?

Comment: @montonero I've been reading about [1900 and 1904 date systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel) and, even though you can set it at worksheet level, the potential side effects are not worth it for what's a mere cosmetic issue.

Comment: Then your option is to cast it to a string as @Akina suggested. This article has a comprehensive description of both methods https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1423-excel-display-show-negative-time.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Data is in J8, you could use the following formula.  It will convert the time to a string, and will check if its negative and add - to the front for negative time.  Unfortunately to deal with it in the future, you will need to convert back from a string to time and deal with carrying the negative sign.

```
=IF(J8<0,"-","")&TEXT(ABS(J8)/60/24,"[H]:MM")
```

Adjust the cell reference to suit your needs.

[image: POC]

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a combination of my original approach and [Forward Ed's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1396616/24651) that allows *positive* values to remain numeric (negative ones are still text, thus are *silently* discarded from calculations):

- Formula:

  ```
  =IF(A1<0, "-" &TEXT(ABS(A1)/60/24, "[H]:MM"), A1/60/24)
  ```
- Cell style:

  ```
  [h]:mm;@
  ```

[image: Screenshot]